Is there any survey about studies of the efficacy of different refueling algorithms as the distance of the graph becomes larger?
Have there been any comprehensive surveys or meta-analyses examining the efficacy of various refueling algorithms(such as this or approximation algorithms etc) across varying graph distances? Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how the performance of these algorithms changes as the distance between nodes in the graph increases
